# Get Custom Class from webservices

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

After calling `Webservices`, it returns an object (This object is a custom object class) to client. So, I want to convert from this object to custom class.

-Webservices:

```
[WebMethod]
public Cls_ROLES GetRoles(int firstNum)
{
    Cls_ROLES o = new Cls_ROLES();
    o.Role_ID = 2;
    o.RoleName = "binh";
    return o;
}
```

-Client:

+Function:

```
public object CallWebService(string webServiceAsmxUrl, string serviceName, string methodName, object[] args)
{
    System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
    //-Connect To the web service
    using (System.IO.Stream stream = client.OpenRead(webServiceAsmxUrl + "?wsdl"))
    {
        //--Now read the WSDL file describing a service.
        ServiceDescription description = ServiceDescription.Read(stream);
        ///// LOAD THE DOM /////////
        //--Initialize a service description importer.
        ServiceDescriptionImporter importer = new ServiceDescriptionImporter();
        importer.ProtocolName = "Soap12"; // Use SOAP 1.2.
        importer.AddServiceDescription(description, null, null);
        //--Generate a proxy client. importer.Style = ServiceDescriptionImportStyle.Client;
        //--Generate properties to represent primitive values.
        importer.CodeGenerationOptions = System.Xml.Serialization.CodeGenerationOptions.GenerateProperties;
        //--Initialize a Code-DOM tree into which we will import the service.
        CodeNamespace nmspace = new CodeNamespace();
        CodeCompileUnit unit1 = new CodeCompileUnit();
        unit1.Namespaces.Add(nmspace);
        //--Import the service into the Code-DOM tree. This creates proxy code
        //--that uses the service.
        ServiceDescriptionImportWarnings warning = importer.Import(nmspace, unit1);
        if (warning == 0) //--If zero then we are good to go
        {
            //--Generate the proxy code 
            CodeDomProvider provider1 = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
            //--Compile the assembly proxy with the appropriate references
            string[] assemblyReferences = new string[5] { "System.dll", "System.Web.Services.dll", "System.Web.dll", "System.Xml.dll", "System.Data.dll" };
            CompilerParameters parms = new CompilerParameters(assemblyReferences);
            CompilerResults results = provider1.CompileAssemblyFromDom(parms, unit1);
            //-Check For Errors
            if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (CompilerError oops in results.Errors)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine("========Compiler error============");
                    sb.AppendLine(oops.ErrorText);
                }
                throw new System.ApplicationException("Compile Error Occured calling webservice. " + sb.ToString());
            }
            //--Finally, Invoke the web service method 
            Type foundType = null;
            Type[] types = results.CompiledAssembly.GetTypes();
            foreach (Type type in types)
            {
                if (type.BaseType == typeof(System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(type.ToString());
                    foundType = type;
                }
            }

            object wsvcClass = results.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance(foundType.ToString());
            MethodInfo mi = wsvcClass.GetType().GetMethod(methodName);
            object o = new object();
            o=mi.Invoke(wsvcClass, args);
            return o;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

+Page_Load function:

```
Line 1:object[] args=new object[1];
Line 2:args[0]=1;  
Line 3:o = this.CallWebService("http://localhost:1814/HelloServices/Service.asmx", "Hello", "GetRoles", args);
```

it returns an object at Line3 (This object is a custom object class) to client. So, I want to convert from this object to custom class(Cls_Role object).
//======================================================================================
//======================================================================================
//======================================================================================
As Selalu_Ingin_Belajar's answer,I can get value from webservices to client fine.

object yourObject = new object();

```
foreach (PropertyInfo property in yourObject.GetType().GetProperties())
{           
    object value = property.GetValue(yourObject , null);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", property.Name, value);
}
```

Beside it,When I apply to another project,It show another error: Parameter count mismatch.
If I use AddWebReference by VisualStudio tool.
It'll auto generate Reference.cs file.It contain:

```
/// <remarks/>
    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapRpcMethodAttribute("", RequestNamespace="urn:ALBAPI", ResponseNamespace="urn:ALBAPI")]
    [return: System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute("info")]
    public ResponseInfo getSetupLicenseRows(out SetupLicenseRowsValues values) {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("getSetupLicenseRows", new object[0]);
        values = ((SetupLicenseRowsValues)(results[1]));
        return ((ResponseInfo)(results[0]));
    }
```

So that,It's easy to call from webClient by passing a object SetupLicenseRowsValues class.
Now,I must pass parameter to WebServices by manually.Don't use this generate file.

Client:

```
public object CallWebService(string webServiceAsmxUrl, string serviceName, string methodName, object[] args)
        {
            System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
            //-Connect To the web service
            using (System.IO.Stream stream = client.OpenRead(webServiceAsmxUrl + "?wsdl"))
            {
                //--Now read the WSDL file describing a service.
                ServiceDescription description = ServiceDescription.Read(stream);
                ///// LOAD THE DOM /////////
                //--Initialize a service description importer.
                ServiceDescriptionImporter importer = new ServiceDescriptionImporter();
                importer.ProtocolName = "Soap12"; // Use SOAP 1.2.
                importer.AddServiceDescription(description, null, null);
                //--Generate a proxy client. importer.Style = ServiceDescriptionImportStyle.Client;
                //--Generate properties to represent primitive values.
                importer.CodeGenerationOptions = System.Xml.Serialization.CodeGenerationOptions.GenerateProperties;
                //--Initialize a Code-DOM tree into which we will import the service.
                CodeNamespace nmspace = new CodeNamespace();
                CodeCompileUnit unit1 = new CodeCompileUnit();
                unit1.Namespaces.Add(nmspace);
                //--Import the service into the Code-DOM tree. This creates proxy code
                //--that uses the service.
                ServiceDescriptionImportWarnings warning = importer.Import(nmspace, unit1);
                if (warning == 0) //--If zero then we are good to go
                {
                    //--Generate the proxy code 
                    CodeDomProvider provider1 = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
                    //--Compile the assembly proxy with the appropriate references
                    string[] assemblyReferences = new string[5] { "System.dll", "System.Web.Services.dll", "System.Web.dll", "System.Xml.dll", "System.Data.dll" };
                    CompilerParameters parms = new CompilerParameters(assemblyReferences);
                    CompilerResults results = provider1.CompileAssemblyFromDom(parms, unit1);
                    //-Check For Errors
                    if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
                    {
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        foreach (CompilerError oops in results.Errors)
                        {
                            sb.AppendLine("========Compiler error============");
                            sb.AppendLine(oops.ErrorText);
                        }
                        throw new System.ApplicationException("Compile Error Occured calling webservice. " + sb.ToString());
                    }
                    //--Finally, Invoke the web service method 
                    Type foundType = null;
                    Type[] types = results.CompiledAssembly.GetTypes();
                    foreach (Type type in types)
                    {
                        if (type.BaseType == typeof(System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(type.ToString());
                            foundType = type;
                        }
                    }

                    object wsvcClass = results.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance(foundType.ToString());
                    MethodInfo mi = wsvcClass.GetType().GetMethod(methodName);
                    object o = new object();
                    Line error: o = mi.Invoke(wsvcClass, new object[0]);
                    return o;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
public void call()
    {
        string WebserviceUrl = "http://192.168.2.19:3333/ALBAPI.wsdl";
        string serviceName = "ALBAPI";
        string methodName = "getSetupLicenseRows";
        object[] args=new object[0];
        object sSessionID = CallWebService(WebserviceUrl, serviceName, methodName,args);
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in sSessionID.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            object value = property.GetValue(sSessionID, null);

            Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", property.Name, value);
        }

    }
```

Now,It show error "Parameter count mismatch" at Line error.
Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: What have you done? Show your effort.

Comment: [Google - Overloading conversion operators C#](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+overloading+conversion+operator)

Comment: Why in the world are you calling web services like that? Just use a Service Reference, or a Web Reference if you're still running .NET 2.0.

Comment: Just want to say thank you, this is very clever and entertaining, although it is a bit insane.

Comment: @Furqan Safdar:I've studied it within 3weeks,It's very easy if we return a string or a double type from webservices to client.But it seem hard when we want to return a custom class.Thanks

Comment: But why go for manually building the proxy on every call instead of using a service reference that would be strongly typed?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: Thanks for your suggestion.It's useful when we perform with default type.When use it in my project.It show "Can't convert from 'Cls_Roles' type to 'Cls_Roles'".Thanks

Comment: @Pablo Romeo and John Saunders:Thanks for your suggestion.Because my project need to connect to multiple services by input address and port manualy.So that,we can't use AddWebReferen as http://www.carlosfemmer.com/post/2008/01/How-to-add-web-reference-in-VS-2008-Project.aspx link.Thanks

Comment: @PabloRomeo: May you give me a link for help to build the proxy on every call.Thanks

Comment: You actually already are creating the proxy on every call. Try using "dynamic" types as mentioned in my answer below. I'll try to expand with an example.

Comment: Now, you do know that even if you add it as a web or service reference, you can still programmatically alter the url and port of the service, correct?

Comment: I wonderd if you have a example for get dynammic type.Thanks bro

Comment: Yes,I can programmatically alter the url and port of the services If we pass parameter to
CallWebService(string webServiceAsmxUrl, string serviceName, string methodName, object[] args) function
Thanks

Comment: Oh, that's not what I meant. I mean generating a real proxy using a service reference or web reference. Not dynamically, but using the IDE. And later, when you create the instance of the proxy, just have it point to whichever endpoint you want by changing the Url property (for web reference) or the EndpointAddress in a service reference.

Answer (score 0):

Now, if i understood correctly, and since you went through the cumbersome effort of dynamically building the proxy (instead of using service references), that would mean that your consumer code, does not contain an actual definition for any of the objects your possible service may return.

In that case I don't see many ways in which through statically typed code you can accomplish that.
You could try using `dynamic` and hope that your response has the "structure" you expect, but without knowing the real type.
Such as:

```
dynamic returnValue = CallWebservice(someEndpoint, someServiceName, ...);
//now you can access all the properties of returnValue, for example:
Console.WriteLine(returnValue.Role_ID);
//but you won't have intellisense, may be error prone, and will prevent you from proper refactoring
```

Comment: Cannot define a class or member that utilizes 'dynamic' because the compiler required type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DynamicAttribute' cannot be found. Are you missing a reference to System.Core.dll?

Comment: I think it will be hard for perform it.Because we must to change return type of CallWebservice(..) function. Beside it,
Console.WriteLine(returnValue.Role_ID);
It'll show error:
One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing references to Microsoft.CSharp.dll and System.Core.dll? 
Thanks for helping

Comment: I don't think you would need to change anything in the CallWebservice function. Are you on C# 4.0?

Comment: Hi bro,I'm on C# 4.0.May you give me any idea.Thanks bro

Comment: It show error "Parameter count mismatch" at Line error now. I edit something at this description.

Comment: I'm still a bit lost about why you want to go through all this madness. Just add a Web Reference or Service reference, and then programmatically change the URL to wherever you need to be in runtime. It is very very uncommon to need to dynamically compile and use proxies in this manner.

Comment: Ah,Thanks bro for your answer.My problem must not to use AddWebReference.It mustn't use in my project. Because user have to input information about webservices such as: IPAddress,Port. Then,Client will use this information for access to Webservices.Do you have any idea?

Comment: Even if the IP address, port, or even protocol are configured through the UI, you can and SHOULD still use a statically created reference. You just need to configure it accordingly in runtime, as i said above in my comments. Just set the Url property if it's a webreference or the endpoint if it's a service reference. See this please: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1193135/1373170

Comment: Dear friend,
I've tried your suggestion.
`<Tab>`
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8888/MyService");

MyServiceClient serviceClient = new MyServiceClient(binding, address);
`$`

Comment: Dear friend,
I've tried your suggestion.
`<Tab>`
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8888/MyService");

MyServiceClient serviceClient = new MyServiceClient(binding, address);
`$`
...............I apply it to my project: ALBAPI obj = new ALBAPI(binding, address);//=====It didn't work.Because my class is defined : public class ALBAPI : SoapHttpClientProtocol.//===Just have a constructor.It's auto generate by Reference.cs file

Comment: I saw this propertities in ALBAPI class.        
public ALBAPI();

        public string Url { get; set; }
        public bool UseDefaultCredentials { get; set; }

Comment: You can trust us, ws proxy urls are indeed configurable. Maybe you can change your question or create a new one with that specific problem, but it is really the common approach to this kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks for sugession,brother.I made a new articles:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244829/connect-multiple-server-by-webservices-from-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `Web/Service Reference` by right clicking on your client project and discover this `Web Service`. Provide appropriate `namespace` name and click OK.

This procedure will automatically generate the `Proxy` of `GetRoles` method along with your custom class type `Cls_ROLES` on your client based on the Schema exposed in `WSDL`.

Comment: Thank bro for suggestion.Because my project need to connect to multiple services by input address and port manualy to a webform.System will save them,afterthat,Using this information for connect to webservices manually.Can't use by your hand for add to visualStudio.So that,we can't use AddWebReferen as carlosfemmer.com/post/2008/01/… link

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to get value of every parameter of the object, you can using reflection.

```
object yourObject = new object();

foreach (PropertyInfo property in yourObject.GetType().GetProperties())
{           
    object value = property.GetValue(yourObject , null);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", property.Name, value);
}
```

but you better using Service Reference like Pablo and Furqan said to get clear schema of your object. Because it will serialize your object automatically , so you dont bother about serialization stuff. Sorry about my english :p

Comment: Thanks bro,I tried and see it work fine.It show propertyName and value fine.Oh,yep,I'll study it more about serialze.Keep in touch with me,bro.Thanks

Comment: Hi brother,I got another error.It show error "Parameter count mismatch" at Line error.I edit at this description.Thanks for your help anyway