# Connect multiple server by webservices from asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, webservices-client

Thanks for reading my question.I wondered if you have any idea about this problem.

1. I wrote a SOAP-SERVER. Running it at CentOS. Changing Soap-Server's IPAddress for match with CentOS Ifconfig.
2. Running SOAP-SERVER in CentOS.
3. Using VisualStudio tools for AddWebReference .It'll auto generate a define object class.In this class,It containt all of function of SOAP-SERVER.
4. Developer will use these function for do something at ASP.Net-Client.

But,When I want to connect from ASP-NET to more SOAP-SERVER(in other CentOSs).And we musn't using AddWebReference .Because User will use web form for input IPAddress of these SOAP-SERVER.

Do you have any idea? Thanks for helping by anyway.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to keep a fixed no. of servers with same IP addresses, otherwise each time you want to access a service you'll have to change the Service proxy classes or service reference in visual studio for that matter.
What you can do is instead of letting the user enter the IP address, display a list all that you have and make him select one.

Comment: Oh,Thanks for your suggesion.I have some idea by your answer.
1.You'll have to keep a fixed no. of servers with same IP addresses ->Each CentOs has IPAddress,So that,we can't fixed no of servers with same IP.
2.you'll have to change the Service proxy classes->I agree with your idea.Thanks,
3.display a list all that you have and make him select one.->He want to add any devices,So that,Developer can't know how many server to access.
Thanks for all of your answer