# How to use Web Service within A Web Application Solution

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, c#-3.0

A web application (ASP.NET Web Project) needs to communicate with a web service (Web Service Project). I am supposed to add web reference (http://xyz.asmx) to web application (http://abc.aspx) to use the interfaces of web service.

BUT,

If a want to add web service project to the web application solution, how I can use web service. Either I need to deploy web service independently or only deploy web application ?

Please guide me in this regard.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5018253/783284

Comment: my question is can web service and web application be deployed under one solution in IIS ?

Answer (score 0):

You should deploy the webservice on your local IIS then you may use it to add webreference to your web application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have a web service and a web application running under the same solution - you just need to configure it in your `web.config`.